# Running JQuery animations in sequence

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to run jquery animations in sequence but cannot seem to get it working...

```
// Run this animation first hiding fading all divs but selected one

if (divid!= '1') { $('#div1').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500); }
if (divid!= '2') { $('#div2').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500); }
if (divid!= '3') { $('#div3').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500); }
if (divid!= '4') { $('#div4').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500); }
if (divid!= '5') { $('#div5').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500); }

once all the above animations have finished do the next lot...

if (cargroup != '1') { $('#div1').hide(500); }
if (cargroup != '2') { $('#div2').hide(500); }
if (cargroup != '3') { $('#div3').hide(500); }
if (cargroup != '4') { $('#div4').hide(500); }
if (cargroup != '5') { $('#div5').hide(500); }
```

and so on...

Comment: May need some more code here. Where do you get `divid` and `cargroup` from? You can just pass the id and animate the right div instead of checking for each like that. Can you provide any more info/expand on your question?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `queue` property of the aninmate method to `true`. It will animate in sequence. Try this

```
if (divid!= '1') { $('#div1').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, { queue: true, duration: 500 }); }
if (divid!= '2') { $('#div2').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, { queue: true, duration: 500 }); }
if (divid!= '3') { $('#div3').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, { queue: true, duration: 500 }); }
if (divid!= '4') { $('#div4').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, { queue: true, duration: 500 }); }
if (divid!= '5') { $('#div5').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, { queue: true, duration: 500 }); }
```

Comment: This will queue each animation, he wants them to execute in groups.

Comment: @Relic - I think thats what OP is looking for.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli what's "OP"... and he clearly has them in groups and wants one set to fire after the other.

Comment: @Relic - OP is the one who has asked this question. Yes, in each group there is a condition and only one will be true I believe.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli Ah, okay so yeah as only one actually gets executed, but I thought okenshield asked. Anyways it'll kinda work, the code is just so messy, like you shouldn't have to parse all that code to also parse the data. Reference my Answer (and due to his naming schema for IDs and Wrappers also is part of the problem)

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options... Try this first `{ queue: true, duration: 500 }` in place of the 500, then try and clean up your logic a little to something more like below.

I have no way of testing this, but it should give you the idea.
And to be honest, I would add a class to all those divs like ".togglers" then do something like this.
And as they're clearly all divs.... try this

```
$(".togglers").each(function(){
    if(divid!=$(this).attr("id")){
        $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500);
    }
});
$(".togglers").each(function(){
    if(cargroup!=$(this).attr("id")){
        $(this).hide(500);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the second block in a function called, lets say, hideDivs() and add this function as callback in the last row of the first block like this:

```
if (divid!= '5') { $('#div5').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500, hideDivs); }
```

EDIT: this is what i mean:

```
if (divid!= '1') { $('#div1').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500); }
if (divid!= '2') { $('#div2').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500); }
if (divid!= '3') { $('#div3').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500); }
if (divid!= '4') { $('#div4').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500); }
if (divid!= '5') { $('#div5').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500, hideDivs); }

function hideDivs() {
   if (cargroup != '1') { $('#div1').hide(500); }
   if (cargroup != '2') { $('#div2').hide(500); }
   if (cargroup != '3') { $('#div3').hide(500); }
   if (cargroup != '4') { $('#div4').hide(500); }
   if (cargroup != '5') { $('#div5').hide(500); }
}
```

Also consider refactoring your code as Relic's post suggests. By using [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), the first block (without your conditionals) could look like this instead:

```
$('#div1, #div2, #div3, #div4, #div5').each(function() {
     if ($(this).attr('id') != 'div5') $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500);
     else $(this).animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500, hideDivs);    
});
```

Comment: This is only going to add to his code by a lot.
'if (divid!= '5') { $('#div5').animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 500, function(){if (cargroup != '5') { $('#div5').hide(500); }
}); } Per line

Answer (score 0):

They won't run in sequence if you do this. All you're doing is queueing the animation and hide effects until control gets back to jQuery - which probably means the blocks just end up hiding. What you need is for each animation to pass a callback function, that is called when the animation completes, and then your callback function starts the next one. See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ and http://api.jquery.com/hide/ for examples.